# Glassfish Server is not starting on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, glassfish-3

When i start the Server it gave me the following Error: I am unable to start the Server.

> Server GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3 (Java EE 6) at localhost
>   failed to start.

The Server log is as follows:

> Jun 11, 2012 8:28:23 PM 
>   com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger
>  info INFO: JVM
>   invocation command line: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\java.exe
>   -cp C:/Java/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
>   -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=192m
>   -XX:NewRatio=2
>   -XX:+LogVMOutput
>   -XX:LogFile=C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/logs/jvm.log
>   -Xmx512m
>   -javaagent:C:/Java/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfishv3/glassfish/lib/monitor/btrace-agent.jar=unsafe=true,noServer=true
>   -client
>   -Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
>   -Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
>   -Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish/modules/autostart/
>   -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
>   -Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
>   -Djava.security.policy=C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
>   -Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
>   -Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1
>   -Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
>   -Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish/modules/endorsed;
> C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish/lib/endorsed
>   -Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish
>   -Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/ext;C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/ext
>   -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
>   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
>   -Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
>   -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
>   -DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
>   -Dfelix.fileinstall.debug=1
>   -Dorg.glassfish.web.rfc2109_cookie_names_enforced=false
>   -Djava.library.path=C:/Java/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfishv3/glassfish/lib;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin;C:/Windows/Sun/Java/bin;C:/Windows/System32;C:/Windows;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:/Windows/System32/wbem;C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0;C:/Java/eclipse;C:/Java/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfishv3/glassfish
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
>   -domainname domain1
>   -asadmin-args start-domain,,,--domaindir,,,C:\Java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains,,,--debug=false,,,--verbose=false,,,domain1
>   -instancename server
>   -verbose false
>   -debug false
>   -asadmin-classpath C:/Java/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/admin-cli.jar
>   -asadmin-classname com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain
>   -upgrade false
>   -domaindir C:/Java/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1
>   -read-stdin true

Comment: There are no errors/exceptions in the currently pasted log, so this log doesn't give any clues. Please edit the question to include the proper log. Also please don't use quote button for logs, but the code button as it will preserve the formatting

Comment: Could you also please mention how you start the glassfish server? (is it from an IDE or from asadmin.bat start-domain or ...) All the log says is the latest command, the one with java.exe

Comment: @esej After installing the Glassfish from eclipse market place i have created a new server in server tab. then i have clicked the server then start. Then it stops at 23% of the process. I did it with Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @BalusC: I have started from your blogspot only. I am struck after installing the Glassfish. I just tried to start.

Comment: @BalusC :  I have solved the problem. I have deleted the osgi-cache Previously i was unable to delete on the system. Even after closing eclipse. then i found the reason that there is a background task running on the system(Java.exe). Anyways thanks you for your guidance in and around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I have deleted the osgi-cache Previously i was unable to delete on the system. Even after closing eclipse. then i found the reason that there is a background task running on the system(Java.exe). Anyways thanks you for your guidance in and around.